# TransactionTooLargeException when starting an activity from a fragment in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I have a ListView inside of a fragment that is supposed to launch another activity on click. Here is the code for that:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position,
                                long id) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), GroupActivity.class);
            startActivity(myIntent);
        }

    });
```

It will appear to load GroupActivity on the emulator screen and then crash with the following exception (Full stack trace):

```
    !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 861936)
Shutting down VM
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 861936 bytes
 at android.app.ActivityThread$StopInfo.run(ActivityThread.java:3752)
 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
Caused by: android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 861936 bytes
 at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
 at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:615)
 at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.activityStopped(ActivityManagerNative.java:3606)
 at android.app.ActivityThread$StopInfo.run(ActivityThread.java:3744)
 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865) 
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

I have tried loading other activities from here and I get the same crash, so it does not appear to be a problem in GroupActivity, but rather in the fragment. Here is the code for the entire fragment:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.packagename.Activities.GroupActivity;
import com.packagename.Models.Group;
import com.packagename.Models.User;
import com.packagename.R;
import com.packagename.util.ArrayAdapters.GroupsListArrayAdapter;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class GroupsFragment extends Fragment {

    // List view
    private ListView listView;
    // Listview Adapter
    public GroupsListArrayAdapter adapter;
    // Search EditText
    EditText inputSearch;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_groups, container, false);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.groups_list_view);
    inputSearch = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);
    loadGroupsForUser();
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position,
                                long id) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), GroupActivity.class);
            startActivity(myIntent);
        }

    });
    //enabling searching groups
    inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            // When user changed the Text
            GroupsFragment.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                                      int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });

}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.add_group, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.add:
            Log.i("log", "add clicked");
            break;
    }
    return true;
}

private void loadGroupsForUser() {
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
    String url = myurl;
    JsonObjectRequest jsonRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(url, null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    try {
                        ArrayList<Group> groups = Group.fromJson(response.getJSONArray("groups"));
                        adapter = new GroupsListArrayAdapter(getContext(), groups);
                        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        }
    });
    // Add the request to the RequestQueue.
    queue.add(jsonRequest);
}

private void moveToGroup() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), GroupActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
}
}
```

I have tried as many solutions as I can think of and can't seem to fix the problem. Launching an activity the same way in one of the onViewCreate methods launches it just fine. It is only when it is being triggered by the listener I have above or even just a separate button. Thanks for any help

Comment: Please post the entire Java stack trace.

Comment: @CommonsWare Sorry about that, done.

Comment: OK, that wasn't as informative as I was hoping. It does show that the crash is triggered by `activityStopped()`. Do any affected activities or fragments have an `onSaveInstanceState()` method? My guess is that you are putting something large, like a `Bitmap`, into the saved instance state `Bundle`.

Comment: Sadly, no. I don't do anything like that which is why this error is driving me mad.